# How to determine the required AND gate in this case?

Tags: digital-logic, ltspice, datasheet, high-speed

I will have two gate inputs A and B to be ANDed; and so far I tried two AND gates: the ideal gate of LTspice and 74HC08 using 74HC library:

[image]

The 74HC08 cannot respond the transitions of inputs but the ideal AND gate can:

[image]

And here is zoomed view shows the plots at during exactly at ANDing time duration:

[image]

And here below the exact time and voltage values of that zoomed section:

```
time    V(a)    V(b)    V(ideal)
0.000000000000000e+000  4.817544e+000   1.714446e-001   0.000000e+000
5.144203554767013e-010  4.817550e+000   1.714404e-001   0.000000e+000
6.124203554766933e-010  4.817072e+000   1.714410e-001   0.000000e+000
6.987005799006947e-010  4.811583e+000   1.753896e-001   0.000000e+000
7.884119137050038e-010  4.795974e+000   1.939303e-001   0.000000e+000
8.026976279907173e-010  4.792693e+000   1.994567e-001   0.000000e+000
8.169833422764307e-010  4.789411e+000   2.049830e-001   0.000000e+000
8.312690565621442e-010  4.786130e+000   2.105094e-001   0.000000e+000
8.455547708478576e-010  4.782848e+000   2.160357e-001   0.000000e+000
8.598404851335712e-010  4.779567e+000   2.215621e-001   0.000000e+000
8.741261994192847e-010  4.776286e+000   2.270884e-001   0.000000e+000
8.884119137049981e-010  4.773004e+000   2.326148e-001   0.000000e+000
9.884119137050056e-010  4.750241e+000   2.833317e-001   0.000000e+000
1.088411913705000e-009  4.723799e+000   3.499716e-001   0.000000e+000
1.188411913704994e-009  4.690145e+000   4.458652e-001   0.000000e+000
1.290411913705004e-009  4.647797e+000   5.917497e-001   0.000000e+000
1.394411913705003e-009  4.595314e+000   7.751039e-001   0.000000e+000
1.494411913705010e-009  4.535233e+000   9.572259e-001   0.000000e+000
1.590411913705000e-009  4.466216e+000   1.131106e+000   0.000000e+000
1.690411913704902e-009  4.375646e+000   1.309612e+000   0.000000e+000
1.790411913704896e-009  4.253656e+000   1.484955e+000   0.000000e+000
1.808697627990612e-009  4.226220e+000   1.516609e+000   0.000000e+000
1.826983342276328e-009  4.198258e+000   1.548120e+000   0.000000e+000
1.845269056562044e-009  4.169771e+000   1.579486e+000   0.000000e+000
1.863554770847760e-009  4.140758e+000   1.610709e+000   0.000000e+000
1.881840485133477e-009  4.111219e+000   1.641788e+000   0.000000e+000
1.900126199419193e-009  4.081155e+000   1.672723e+000   0.000000e+000
1.918411913704909e-009  4.050565e+000   1.703515e+000   0.000000e+000
1.972697627990620e-009  3.957443e+000   1.794183e+000   0.000000e+000
2.026983342276332e-009  3.863964e+000   1.883341e+000   0.000000e+000
2.081269056562044e-009  3.770128e+000   1.970988e+000   0.000000e+000
2.135554770847755e-009  3.675936e+000   2.057126e+000   0.000000e+000
2.189840485133466e-009  3.581386e+000   2.141754e+000   0.000000e+000
2.244126199419178e-009  3.486481e+000   2.224871e+000   0.000000e+000
2.298411913704890e-009  3.391218e+000   2.306478e+000   0.000000e+000
2.418411913704907e-009  3.181144e+000   2.488142e+000   0.000000e+000
2.438411913704903e-009  3.146028e+000   2.518174e+000   5.000000e+000
2.802411913704905e-009  2.504136e+000   3.063299e+000   5.000000e+000
2.818411913704910e-009  2.475772e+000   3.087231e+000   0.000000e+000
2.941269056562037e-009  2.257395e+000   3.270982e+000   0.000000e+000
3.064126199419164e-009  2.038858e+000   3.454730e+000   0.000000e+000
3.186983342276292e-009  1.820159e+000   3.638476e+000   0.000000e+000
3.309840485133419e-009  1.601300e+000   3.822219e+000   0.000000e+000
3.432697627990546e-009  1.382279e+000   4.005959e+000   0.000000e+000
3.555554770847673e-009  1.163098e+000   4.189696e+000   0.000000e+000
3.678411913704800e-009  9.437553e-001   4.373431e+000   0.000000e+000
3.790411913704808e-009  7.447242e-001   4.540740e+000   0.000000e+000
3.888411913704800e-009  5.714831e-001   4.677907e+000   0.000000e+000
3.898959863826857e-009  5.534172e-001   4.688203e+000   0.000000e+000
3.909507813948915e-009  5.353513e-001   4.698498e+000   0.000000e+000
3.920055764070972e-009  5.172854e-001   4.708794e+000   0.000000e+000
3.930603714193029e-009  4.992195e-001   4.719089e+000   0.000000e+000
3.941151664315086e-009  4.811536e-001   4.729385e+000   0.000000e+000
3.951699614437144e-009  4.630877e-001   4.739681e+000   0.000000e+000
3.962247564559201e-009  4.450218e-001   4.749976e+000   0.000000e+000
4.035933589666995e-009  3.369395e-001   4.783496e+000   0.000000e+000
4.101570564570403e-009  2.668940e-001   4.796039e+000   0.000000e+000
4.173103368179993e-009  2.200216e-001   4.802926e+000   0.000000e+000
4.252327782995998e-009  1.952324e-001   4.807043e+000   0.000000e+000
4.271988513932098e-009  1.921481e-001   4.807720e+000   0.000000e+000
4.291649244868198e-009  1.894059e-001   4.808346e+000   0.000000e+000
4.311309975804298e-009  1.870057e-001   4.808921e+000   0.000000e+000
4.330970706740399e-009  1.849477e-001   4.809446e+000   0.000000e+000
4.350631437676498e-009  1.832317e-001   4.809920e+000   0.000000e+000
4.370292168612599e-009  1.818578e-001   4.810345e+000   0.000000e+000
4.389952899548698e-009  1.808260e-001   4.810718e+000   0.000000e+000
4.440683916830996e-009  1.788714e-001   4.811516e+000   0.000000e+000
4.491414934113294e-009  1.772400e-001   4.812213e+000   0.000000e+000
4.542145951395591e-009  1.759319e-001   4.812808e+000   0.000000e+000
4.592876968677889e-009  1.749469e-001   4.813301e+000   0.000000e+000
4.643607985960187e-009  1.742851e-001   4.813693e+000   0.000000e+000
4.694339003242485e-009  1.739466e-001   4.813984e+000   0.000000e+000
4.745070020524783e-009  1.739312e-001   4.814172e+000   0.000000e+000
4.994235291871728e-009  1.725789e-001   4.815326e+000   0.000000e+000
5.000000000000005e-009  1.725644e-001   4.815343e+000   0.000000e+000
```

So in reality I will have the same A and B inputs to an AND gate and I want to obtain something very close to the ideal AND output above. I came across [this gate](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/nc7sz08-d.pdf) so far but I cannot interpret its datasheet so that I can conclude whether it would work. Would that Ultra−High Speed AND gate result fine in this case? How to determine the required part in this case?

Comment: Perhaps not an answer to your question but if you right click on the ideal gate, you can add propagation delay from the datasheet and get a first order approximation if it will be ok in your application. See more here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/532582/ltspice-behavioral-modelling-elements-for-propagation-delay and here: https://ltwiki.org/LTspiceHelp/LTspiceHelp/A_Special_functions_.htm

Comment: I see maybe could you write an answer showing that for my case? I have limited experience with digital logic ICs.

Comment: One idea might be to use an 74LVC08A powered with 3.3V.  LVC series inputs are 5V tolerant and they'll read valid high inputs around that transition region you're interested in.  The output pulses will swing between 0V and 3.3V, so if you need it back to 5V you'll have to use some kind of level translation scheme afterward.  Keep in mind that you're dealing with sub-nanosecond precision here so it's going to be hard to get a solution that works reliably in that range.

Comment: @SteKulov Thanks for the input. But in this case shouldn't it be an ultrafast type of gate? And how to check whether  74LVC08A is fast enough at least theoretically by looking at datasheet and comparing some specs to my transition duration ect. That I dont know how to do; and was one of the reason I asked this question.

Comment: How about this gate: https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/hmc722lc3c.pdf

Comment: My suggestion deals with helping the **inputs** detect the applied logic states.  A faster gate will allow the **output** to swing from one state to the other.  So both would help address your problem.  Like others have mentioned, the gate itself is only one factor since the characteristics of your load along with any parasitic capacitance will influence the performance just as much.  Probably the only way to validate without just trying things on the bench (using an expensive high-speed oscilloscope) would be to try various SPICE and/or IBIS models.  Might have to roll your own too...

Comment: That Analog Devices gate is fast because it uses differential signaling similar to ECL logic.  If that's an option, then it greatly improves the feasibility of what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking for a logic AND gate that will do what you want, there is no such thing.

Logic gates only have specified behaviour when the input voltage is within their guarranteed validity high and low regions. It appears from your second diagram that you are looking for specific behaviour when the inputs are in the mid-range region.

You can create an analogue circuit, that you can tailor with appropriate thresholds and speeds, to do what you want.

Logic, when presented with waveforms like that, will do whatever it happens to do, and not necessarily do the same thing next time you apply them (perhaps at a different temperature) and not necessarily when you apply them to another AND gate of the same type (perhaps slightly different thresholds and speeds).

Comment: But I saw circuits using this ANDing to create such output. Its not my invention.

Comment: @pnatk  Resulting in pulses that were only hundreds of picoseconds or was it on a much different scale?

Comment: @pnatk I don't doubt you could have seen this behaviour. However, it's not reproducible, not robustly. Logic doesn't really care what happens in the middle, so it isn't specified or controlled for it. Of course, logic gates are analogue inside, so they will do *something*, but what you see is what you get now, and the chance of getting the same thing at another temperature or with another gate is remote.

Answer (score 4):

You have two signals, A and B, where A is the inverse of B. In boolean algebra this is written \$A = \bar B\$. This means that theoretically A is *never* equal to B. The AND operation can yield true (high) *only* when both inputs are high, and since that can never happen, you are asking for the impossible.

In real life signals A and B will spend some time between high and low states, because there's no such thing as an instant transition. Your "ideal" AND gate is responding with instant output transitions, which are impossible in real life, but possible in a simulator. It also has sharply defined switching thresholds, another property that doesn't exist in real life.

The 74HC08 (or any other real life gate) will not be able to swing its output from high to low, or back, fast enough in those "in-between", poorly defined  states of A and B, for you to see any clearly defined high output pulse. Nor is it likely to interpret the voltages when A is on its way up while B is falling (and vice versa) as being "the same" (both high, or both low) at any point. Consequently a real-life AND gate's behaviour during those input transitions is completely undefined and unpredictable.

There is a solution - delay one of the inputs, A or B, by a few nanoseconds. That would have the effect of allowing the two inputs to actually be simultaneously high for a short period, high (in the sense of what the datasheet's specification of what constitutes a high input) long enough to allow the AND gate's output to reach a *real* high level.

Such a delay can be introduced with a single additional gate in the path of either input. Since you seem OK using a 74HC08, you could use one of its spare gates like G1 here:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHUHnp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

A and B are the same signal, but 180° out of phase with each other. Gate G1 introduces a 10ns delay, which can be seen in the plot of voltages A2 and B:

[image]

This delay allows A2 and B to be simultaneously high for about 10ns, just enough time for gate G2 to detect and respond to that condition. G2's output will be something like:

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. But I can already introduce delay to A or B inputs. And already there's is very short delay between A and B deliberately introduced delay. To produce very short output. I want to produce the output which is around 700ps pulse width or even less. In simulation it is like 400ps. Will your method stretch the output pulse width or keep it short close to the simulation output?

Comment: So my aim is not to detect those transitions but to obtain an output with <1ns pulse width.  I saw this technique in a Jim Williams book. They say the width of the pulse depends on the speed of the AND gate where they mention they gone down to 700ps or even less as far as I remember.

Comment: You can't expect sub-nanosecond pulses from 74HC devices. I don't know of any discrete logic devices that can do this, even fast 74AC ones. The only way I know of achieving such fast response and transitions is with gates extremely close to each other, such as those you find inside the ICs themselves. This is one of the reasons FPGAs can achieve such ludicrous speeds. However, once the signal leaves the IC, onto long paths, it becomes subject to parasitic capacitances and inductances that make transporting the signals intact very difficult indeed.

Comment: I see. And in my question I also asked about this one https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/nc7sz08-d.pdf ultrafast type. But no one commented on it. Btw here I found the circuit https://www.electronics-lab.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/LT1721.png

Comment: That datasheet doesn't say what the output rise and fall times are, but I suspect that they will be well in excess of 1ns. This means the gate can't give you an output pulse less than a couple of nanoseconds wide.

Comment: Also, it's not just the gate itself which imposes these limits - the thing that the gate is driving (whatever comes after) will cause the gate's output to slew slower than an unloaded output.

Comment: Also see here page 110(page 104 of pdf): http://www.introni.it/pdf/Williams%2005%20-%202000-2011%20-%20EDN.pdf They say "The partial-amplitude
pulse, 3.3V high, measures 700 psec wide with a 1.25-nsec base. The
trace granularity is an artifact of the..."

Comment: @pnatk note that Williams used a variable delay between the inputs of his gate.

Comment: @JohnDoty Of course, I did the same just RC values tweaked in my case.